# Springboot integration tests are failing when adding multiple service

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing, rest

I have a spring boot application with one controller class, one Service and one repository working perfectly fine. I have added Junit test cases for the same and that is also working perfectly fine.

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Employee> getEmployee(){
       return service.findAll();
    }
}


@Service
public class EmployeeService{
   
   @Autowired
   EmployeeRepository repository;

   public List<Employee> findAll(){
      return repository.findAll();
   }
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String>{}
```

The test class is below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = EmployeeController.class)
class EmployeeControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private EmployeeService service;

    @Test
    public void findAllEmployeeTest(){
    }
}
```

The test case is passing until here, but at the moment I am adding another API as below all tests are failing.

```
@RestController
public class DepartmentController{
    @Autowired
    DepartmentService service;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Department> getDepartment(){
       return service.findAll();
    }
}


@Service
public class DepartmentService{
   
   @Autowired
   DepartmentRepository repository;

   public List<Department> findAll(){
      return repository.findAll();
   }
}
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, String>{}
```

The test class is below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = DepartmentController.class)
class DepartmentControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DepartmentService service;

    @Test
    public void findAllDepartmentTest(){
    }
}
```

After adding the Department services test cases are failing with below error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'departmentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.employeeapp.data.repository.DepartmentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For what i see, you try to do an IT test by mocking your service. In IT test you don't mock your service. In Integration Test you test that all work together. If you don't mock  the repository it's more an E2E Test (end to end you test all the interaction path).

You can mock the repository if there is no logic to test, and/or don't want to write in your database.

So if it's unit test you can try that (it work on my projects) and i use Junit 5 (org.junit.jupiter)

```java
    @WebMvcTest(DepartementController.class)
    public class DepartementControllerTest {
    
      @MockBean
      private DepartmentService departmentService;
    
    
      @Autowired
      MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test
    public void findAllTest(){
     // You can create a list for the mock to return
    when(departmentService.findAll()).thenReturn(anyList<>);
    
    //check if the controller return something
    assertNotNull(departmentController.findAll());
    
    //you check if the controller call the service
    Mockito.verify(departmentService, Mockito.times(1)).findAll(anyList());
    }
```

That's a unit test.

An It test will be more like

```java
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class DepartmentIT {
    
    
      @Autowired
      DepartmentService departmentService;
    
      @Autowired
      private WebApplicationContext wac;
    
      private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
      @BeforeEach
      void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc =
                MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                        .build();
      }
    
      @Test
      void departmentFindAll() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/YOUR_CONTROLLER_URL")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andReturn();
    
        
assertTrue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString().contains("SOMETHING_EXPECTED"));
        assertTrue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString().contains("SOMETHING_EXPECTED"));
        assertTrue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString().contains("SOMETHING_EXPECTED"));
    
    //You also can check its not an empty list, no errors are thrown etc...
    
      }
```

the imports use so you dont search too much are

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

> `No qualifying bean of type 'com.employeeapp.data.repository.DepartmentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

Spring looks for the bean of **TYPE**: `DepartmentRepository`.

1. Define the Bean

```java
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, String>{}
```

Add the annotation here `@Repository` so Spring can turn `DepartmentRepository` into a Bean.

2. Autowire the Correct Type and Name

```java
@Service
public class DepartmentService{
   
   @Autowired
   private DepartmentRepository repository; // The best practice is to write the full bean name here departmentRepository.

   public List<Department> findAll(){
      return repository.findAll();
   }
}
```